# Export a SQL Server Express DB to a .SDF file (Local DB)

Tags: sql, visual-studio, ssms, localdb

I have a couple DB on my server, that I would like to export to my laptop for developing against when on the road on offline.

I have a SQL Server 2008 database that I would like to export to a `.SDF` (local DB file). There seems to be lots of info going from `.SDF` to T-SQL, but nothing that will go the other way.

I tried exporting schema and data as SQL scripts, and then running it as a query in Visual Studio's `.SDF` connection, but none of the create statements were supported.

This must be common task, how can I not find a solution for it?

I have SSMS 2012 installed.

Comment: If you have SSMS 2012 installed on your laptop, why don't you just dismount the database(s) and copy their files to your laptop - or do a backup/restore? Why go to local DB?

Comment: good question. Mainly, is I run Windows on a VM in my laptop, and I am trying to keep the VB as light as possible, thus not doing a full blown install of SQL Server Express would be best.

Comment: One clarification. SDF is file format of SQL Server Compact. SQL Server Express LocalDB uses MDF file format, the same as all SQL Server editions (except Compact). If you want to develop for SQL Server then you should consider simply using LocalDB for your development environment.

Comment: Thanks KK, I had missed that. Maybe part of the reason my search had come up empty so far.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25685/SQL-Server-to-SQL-Server-Compact-Edition-Database) or [Here](http://erikej.blogspot.com/2010/02/how-to-use-exportsqlce-to-migrate-from.html) are some tools that should do the job.

Comment: I have already downloaded the 2nd one you list, but it is only for going the other way: sdf -> SQL.  The first link I had come across already, but it seems to be outdated, but I did find this based off the solution you mention: https://github.com/pmiossec/SQL2SQLCompact